# Как подружить gulp-browser-sync и PhpStorm

Tags: php, frontend, gulp, phpstorm, browsersync

Каким образом связать Gulp-browser-sync и PhpStorm. С файлами .html проблем нет, а вот с .php плагин не может получить доступ. При настройке browser-sync в gulpfile.js люди указывают proxy. Но я никак не могу понять откуда его взять в PS

Comment: .php файлы это не html, им нужен сервер (и сам сайт на сервере), без него открывать в браузере файлы бессмысленно

Comment: там в PS же есть свой встроенный сервер

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге у меня не получилось настроить browser-sync без использования "Open Server", поэтому просто установил его. В настройках gulpfile.js заменил server: на proxy:

```
function browserSync() {
    browsersync.init({
        proxy: 'my project domain',
        notify: false
    });
}
```

Использование 'build-in-preview' от PhpStorm оказалось не совсем удобным и я бы даже сказал замороченным